# How could I watch a prop in the composition api?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-props

How can I call a function when a prop is updated?

parent container:

```
<div>     
  <Maintable :type="typeRef" :country="countryRef" />
</div>
```

child container:

```
    export default{

    props: ['type'],
    
    setup(props)
    {   
        watch(props.type, () => {
            console.log('hello')
        })
    }
```

this code gets an error: Invalid watch source...
How can I listen for an update of tthe props?

Hope someone can help me out!! :-)

Answer (score 31):

Try to return the prop from function as first parameter :

```js
    export default{

    props: ['type'],
    
    setup(props)
    {   
        watch(()=>props.type, (newVal) => {
            console.log('hello')
        })
    }
```

Instead of `watch(props.type`, do `watch(()=>props.type`, because `()=>props.type` is an arrow function that returns the prop and it's the parameter of the watcher property.

**Note :**

if you want to watch a **property of an object** you should use a getter, but if you want to watch the **whole object** or a reactive primitive variable pass it directly as first parameter and add `deep:true` option

Comment: This solution works and it's great. But I can understand why we need a getter sometimes and not in other cases.

Comment: Good question; if you want to watch a **property of an object** you should use a getter, but if you want to watch the **whole object** or a reactive primitive variable pass it directly as first parameter and add `deep:true` option

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I think we can also watch a property of an object without getter if it is an object. and the watch will be deep if I am not mistaken

Comment: It doesn't a matter if the property is an object or not, if you want to access a property you always use a getter

Answer (score 2):

You have two possible solutions:

1. Your can make a computed property and watch it

```js
import {computed, watch} from 'vue';

export default {
  props: ['type'],

  setup(props) {
    const type = computed(() => props.type);

    watch(type, (newValue) => {
      console.log('hello');
    });
  }
}
```

2. You can use arrow function like this

```js
import {watch} from 'vue';

export default {

  props: ['type'],

  setup(props) {   
    watch(() => props.type, (newValue) => {
        console.log('hello');
    });
  }
}
```