# Vue 3 watch variable code not being fired when value changes

Tags: vue.js

Vue 3.4.21

I have a child component and I watch one of the prop values:

```
  const props = defineProps({
    location_id: Array,
    daterange: Array,
    showtable: Boolean
  })
      watch(showtable, () => {
        alert('showtable value is:'+showtable.value)
        if (showtable.value) {
           alert('do some work')
         }
      })
```

I use the child component in a parent component and pass the required props:

```
    const showtable = ref(false);
    const selectedLocations = ref([]);
    const dateRange = ref();

  <DataTable :location_id="selectedLocations" :daterange="dateRange" :showtable="showtable" />
```

I also have a button in my parent component and when it is pressed, I check to make sure a daterange and location are provided. If the are, then an api call is made:

```
  const getAppointments = () => {
    showtable.value = false
    const dates = toRaw(dateRange.value)
    const locs = toRaw(selectedLocations.value)
    if (dates?.length && locs?.length)
      showtable.value = true
  }
```

When the page loads, if i select a location and daterange, both alert boxes appear in the  showtable watch and the api call is made if showtable is true

I click the button again without changing location or daterange and nothing happens. I change the daterange and/or location, click again, nothing happens.

I remove a value (either daterange or location) by unchecking them, the watch code fires and showtable is of course false, so no api call is made. Which is fine, but I don't understand why the watch code fired in this scenario.

The watch code should fire everytime I click the button if location and daterange values are present because I change showtable's value to false when the click function is first entered and change showtable value to true if criteria is met.

How do I make the watch code for my showtable variable fire whenever I change its value?

Thanks

P.S. - I put a watcher on location and daterange and the watch code fired everytime their values changed. Its just my boolean showtable giving me problems

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67048615/8172857

Comment: No showtable is defined in child comp. You describe a considerable amount of code, while it should be presented in the question. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Don't use alert for debugging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dude, you're watch a `showtable` that doesn't exist. There is `props.showtable`, and to watching exactly this property, use the function in `watch`:

```js
/* App.vue */

<script setup>
import Comp from './Comp.vue'
import { ref } from 'vue'

const isSowtable = ref(false)
</script>

<template>
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="isSowtable">
  <Comp :showtable="isSowtable"></Comp>
</template>
```

```
/* Comp.vue */

<script setup>
import { watch } from 'vue'
const props = defineProps({
  location_id: Array,
  daterange: Array,
  showtable: Boolean
})
watch(() => props.showtable, newValue => {
  alert('showtable value is:' + newValue)
  if (newValue) {
    alert('do some work')
  }
})
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    {{ showtable }}
  </div>
</template>
```

[**Vue SFC Playground**](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)